# Python- Can I make a celery worker free for a period of time programmatically?

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to implement a celery task that would call a API which takes about 10-15 seconds to execute. After calling the API I need to poll for the result using http-get. Now I want to poll for results every 2 seconds which means the worker would be free for those 2 seconds. Can I somehow tell celery that that particular worker would be free for that period of time?
Let me know if I haven't made myself clear.

Comment: You mean to say you want to delay a task for 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to delay a celery task.

```
1st:

>>> tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
>>> add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], eta=tomorrow)

2nd:
>>> result = add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], countdown=3)
>>> result.get()    # this takes at least 3 seconds to return
```

Source : https://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown

Comment: So, this doesn't mean that the worker executing **add** will be busy for the next 3 seconds?

Comment: I want to free the worker, save it's context and run it again in a 3 second delay if the response is not none. For e.g. Say if **add** only takes 1 second to execute, will the worker be free for the next 2 seconds?

Comment: No. It does not mean it is busy for 3 sec. But will be executed after 3 sec